# React Socket io client отправка файлов

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, сокет, socket.io

Всем привет, стоит задача через React Socket io client отправка файлов на бэк и сохранить их. Бэк на node js тоже через socket io. Сама суть вопроса что можно ли отправить на реакте файлы через Socket io client. Например socket.emit("message:add", {
message: 'Привет',
files: [массив из файлов],
}); без дополнительных библиотек

Answer (score 2):

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const [stateComponent, setStateComponent] = React.useState({
  files: [],
  uploading: false
});


useEffect(() => {
  if (socket && stateComponent.files.length > 0) {

    const obj = []
    stateComponent.files.map((f, index) => {
      const arr = {
        filename: f.name,
        file: f
      }
      return obj.push(arr)
    })
    socket.emit('start-transfer', {
      obj
    }) /// send files 
  }
}, [stateComponent.files.length])

const handleOnChangeInput = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const array_files = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
    let file = event.target.files[i];
    if (!stateComponent.files.map(n => n.name).includes(file.name)) {
      array_files.push(file);
    }
  }
  setStateComponent({
    files: [...stateComponent.files, ...array_files],
    uploading: false
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



<input type="file" value={stateComponent.files.name} onChange={handleOnChangeInput} />
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]